# How to start custom applications as root automatically on boot?

Tags: login

I have made a sound based installation using OpenFrameworks and Puredata that runs on Ubuntu 12.10.

I need the installation to run continuously for days together. When the power goes off, i need the apps to start automatically on reboot.

My problem is, I have got everything installed in the root account because that is how few of them would run. So i need the system to run those programs as root without asking for a password.

Somehow it sounds very silly to me but I guess there must be a way to do this.

Any help/pointers are appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Have you considered just adding the applications to a root executed start up script? either /etc/rc.local or somewhere in /etc/init.d/

Comment: logging in as root is not necessary and is very dangerous. I edited your question so you will get answers about how to do it properly.

Comment: "So I need the system to run those programs as root without asking for a password."
That defeats Ubuntu's security system altogether. A huge risk I wouldn't want to take, if you ask me.

Comment: @ImaginaryRobots Thank you. That is what I need to do basically :)

Comment: @Mochan : Thats why i added "it sounds very silly to me" in the question itself :) The thing is that PC is only going to be used for this art installation henceforth and it is meant to run for a long time.

Comment: I advise looking into [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/392402/78161) (the part about setting the same permissions). If you don't know how to do that, there will no doubt be an already answered question on here about that. Good luck :P

Comment: @virtualxtc : i didnt know about rc.local. I did some reading up on it. I added commands to the file but it does not start on start up it seems. I ensured that it was executable. And I have made sure that there is not error in the script itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitely check out http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html as that's probably the route you want to go.

Another route would be to add the commands you want run as root to your /etc/rc.local file

Finally, it's really not advisable to be logging-in in as root at all, let alone auto-logging-in in as root.  Nevertheless, one could just  assign your user all the same permissions as root via user management.

Comment: adding the commands to /etc/rc.local did the trick :)
Thank you!